# no such target '@maven//:io_lettuce_lettuce_core': target 'io_lettuce_lettuce_core' not declared in package

Tags: maven, kotlin, bazel

I am trying to write a very simple example in kotlin to interact with redis.

I want to use bazel to drive the build process.

Here is the WORKSOPACE file

```
workspace(
    name = "com_ahwkong_kotlin",
    managed_directories = {},
)

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

RULES_KOTLIN_VERSION = "legacy-1.4.0-rc3"
RULES_KOTLIN_SHA = "da0e6e1543fcc79e93d4d93c3333378f3bd5d29e82c1bc2518de0dbe048e6598"
http_archive(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_kotlin",
    urls = ["https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_kotlin/releases/download/%s/rules_kotlin_release.tgz" % RULES_KOTLIN_VERSION],
    sha256 = RULES_KOTLIN_SHA,
)

load("@io_bazel_rules_kotlin//kotlin:kotlin.bzl", "kotlin_repositories", "kt_register_toolchains")
kotlin_repositories() # if you want the default. Otherwise see custom kotlinc distribution below
kt_register_toolchains() # to use the default toolchain, otherwise see toolchains below


# maven
RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG = "2.8"
RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_SHA = "79c9850690d7614ecdb72d68394f994fef7534b292c4867ce5e7dec0aa7bdfad"

http_archive(
    name = "rules_jvm_external",
    strip_prefix = "rules_jvm_external-%s" % RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG,
    sha256 = RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_SHA,
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/archive/%s.zip" % RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG,
)

load("@rules_jvm_external//:defs.bzl", "maven_install")

maven_install(
    artifacts = [
        "com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9",
        "com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.0.18",
        "com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.1",
    ],
    repositories = [
        "https://jcenter.bintray.com/",
        "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2",
    ],
)
```

This is my BUILD file

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_kotlin//kotlin:kotlin.bzl", "kt_compiler_plugin", "kt_jvm_library", "kt_jvm_binary")

kt_compiler_plugin(
    name = "open_for_testing_plugin",
    id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.allopen",
    options = {
        "annotation": "plugin.allopen.OpenForTesting",
    },
    deps = [
        "@com_github_jetbrains_kotlin//:allopen-compiler-plugin",
    ],
)


kt_jvm_library(
    name = "ex1_lib",
    srcs = glob(["ex1*/src/**/*.kt"]),
    deps = [
        "@maven//:io_lettuce_lettuce_core",
    ]
)

java_binary(
    name = "ex1",
    main_class = "ex1.App",
    srcs = glob(["ex1*/src/**/*.kt"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    runtime_deps = [":ex1_lib"],
)
```

This is my kotlin file

```
package ex1

import io.lettuce.core.RedisClient
import io.lettuce.core.RedisReactiveCommandsImpl
import io.lettuce.core.RedisURI
import io.lettuce.core.api.StatefulRedisConnection
import io.lettuce.core.api.reactive.RedisReactiveCommands
import java.time.Duration

class ConnectionFactory {
  // https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/objects-and-companion-objects.html
  // If you need a function or a property to be tied to a class rather than to instances of it
  // (similar to @staticmethod in Python), you can declare it inside a companion object:
  companion object {
    fun createConnection(port: Int = 6380, host: String = "127.0.0.1"): RedisClient =
        RedisClient.create(RedisURI.builder()
            .withTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
            .withHost(host)
            .withPort(port)
            .build())
  }
}
```

Without the maven dependency I will not be able to compile the above code.

Here is the error message:

```
$ bazel build ex1
ERROR: /Users/antkong/dev/canva/kongakong-experiments.3.diagrams/tech_talk/kotlin/BUILD:26:1: no such target '@maven//:io_lettuce_lettuce_core': target 'io_lettuce_lettuce_core' not declared in package '' defined by /private/var/tmp/_bazel_antkong/3496a0772a2021d0f0b3c230bf912ab1/external/maven/BUILD and referenced by '//:ex1_lib'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:ex1' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
```

If the issue is "no such target '@maven//:io_lettuce_lettuce_core', how can I define this target?

Answer (score 2):

I need to add this rule to the WORKSPACE

```
 maven_repositories = [
     "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/",
     "https://s3.amazonaws.com/maven.canva-build.com/release/",
     "https://github.com/getdyspatch/dyspatch-java-mvn/raw/master/releases/",
 ]

maven_install(
    artifacts = [
        "io.lettuce:lettuce-core:jar:5.3.4.RELEASE",
    ],
    repositories = maven_repositories,
)
```